# Dynamic Background image in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my very first post on stack overflow, so apologies if i am doing anything outside of the norm here.

i have a very simple question. i am learning Vue.js, and want to have some background image repeat in my BODY, but adding that image in a dynamic fashion

until now i have managed to do so in a classic DIV like so in the HTML part of the code:

```
<template>
    <div  :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundUrl})` }">test</div>
</template>
```

and in the Vue.js script i have this :

```
<script>
import backgroundUrl from '~/artistes/ElzoDurt.jpg'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      backgroundUrl
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now this works perfectly fine in a DIV, because i am using TEMPLATE
but trying the same trick in a BODY doesn't seem to function because if i ever use BODY within a TEMPLATE , the screen goes blank !

Thank you very much !

Comment: I've just created [simple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xnwq3f) case with your example, seems it working fine, although it is not right way to do it.

Comment: If you want do it to `page body`, you should use `document.body` and change styles in mounted or where ever you want.

Comment: In Vue 2, you can either do this on an absolutely positioned full height/width div or directly manipulate the `<body>` DOM, because you can't mount Vue onto the `<body>` tag.  In Vue 3, you can mount to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: thank you ! i need some time to digest that, i tried the first method with no success because of TEMPLATE wich leaves everything blank, but i need to try harder probably